# Issue with PIR sensor

Tags: sensors

I have been using a HC-SR501 PIR module with my Arduino Mega and it was tracking presence pretty well.

Because of cost constraints, I decided to go with the low cost HC-SR505 sensor - bought a bunch of them. The performance is very bad. It almost seems like it is giving random HIGH and LOW values. Out of the 20 odd sensors I bought, may be one or two are fairly ok - others are all behaving weird. Have someone experienced this kind of behavior with HC-SR505 sensor?

Are they highly sensitive to noise in the power supply - is there any workaround to mitigate the effect? Would an RC filter across the input help?